Достать информацию о медиафайле формата mpd
ffprobe /144.mp4

Все отлично, достает всю интересующую инфу. Битрейты, потоки...
А как быть, если формат mp4 был преобразован по технологии dash? Сделал так
ffprobe /dash.mpd

И это все что он выдал
ffprobe version N-100470-g5b48d2a Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-libs=-lm --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-libwebp --enable-pic --enable-ffplay --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nonfree --enable-openssl --enable-libx265 --enable-libwebp
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 94.100 /  7. 94.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
/dash.mpd: Invalid data found when processing input

Ни битрейт, ничего. Как узнать битрейт данного формата?

mpd это не медиафайл, а текстовый файл с информацией о том, где искать эти самые медиафайлы, и по прописанным в mpd-файле местам они должны существовать

Ну и собственно у меня на корректном mpd-файле с корректными видеофайлами ffprobe прекрасно отрабатывает, значит вы там сами у себя что-то сломали

А ещё 2020 год это ОЧЕНЬ давно, с тех пор поддержка dash в ffmpeg сильно допиливалась, обновитесь
